# How to SUM a Column based on another column in DAX Powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot, dax

Here is the example,

```
+------+----+
| CARS |  3 |
| CARS |  4 |
| CARS |  6 |
| CARS | 76 |
| CARS |  4 |
| CARS |  3 |
| SUV  | 32 |
| SUV  |  3 |
| SUV  |  3 |
| SUV  |  2 |
| SUV  |  3 |
| SUV  |  5 |
+------+----+
```

I want to add a new calculated column with data like this

```
+------+----+------+
| CARS |  3 |  96  |
| CARS |  4 |  96  |
| CARS |  6 |  96  |
| CARS | 76 |  96  |
| CARS |  4 |  96  |
| CARS |  3 |  96  |
| SUV  | 32 |  48  |
| SUV  |  3 |  48  |
| SUV  |  3 |  48  |
| SUV  |  2 |  48  |
| SUV  |  3 |  48  |
| SUV  |  5 |  48  |
+------+----+------+
```

Where it would sum up the number column for the type of vehicle. What would be the DAX command to get this? I need a third column that sums up all Cars..that is 96 for the CARS row, and sums up all Suvs, that is 48 for all rows that are suvs. Please help

Answer (score 5):

You can create a calculated measure to accomplish this.  I imported your data into a Power Pivot model. Then I added the following calculated measure:

```
Type Subtotal:=CALCULATE( SUM( [Value]), ALLEXCEPT(Table2, Table2[Type]))
```

[image]

So when I make a pivot table I get the desired result.

[image]